# Error: name 'np' is not defined in generating random numbers

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from numpy import random
#### Q_1
#1. What is the age range of your typical patients with retina-based diseases?
Q_1 = np.random.choice(['Below 40', '40-49', '50-59', '60-69', 'Above 70'], p=[.1,.2,.4,.2,.1], size=(500))

#print(Q_1, type(Q_1), sep="\n\n")

df_Q1 = pd.DataFrame(Q_1) 

# df

df_Q1.to_csv("Question_One.csv")

print('!')
```

tried having the two in separate cells the import and random choice but all failed

Comment: Make sure to execute the cells in order. Or put everything in the same cell

Comment: Are you sure if this line was executed `import numpy as np` ? May be you restarted the kernel and forgot to execute this line again after restarting.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Answer (score 0):

Check installation numpy within your kernel and import numpy doesn't give error
Check numpy version